# Can ffmpeg merge multiple m4a files into one ~chapterized~ file?

Tags: audio, macos, audiobook, open-source

Given a folder full of 'm4a' files, I can merge them all into one big m4a file using `ffmpeg` like so:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in ./*.m4a; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) \
-c copy ../OUTPUT.m4a
```

However, what I would like to do is have `OUTPUT.m4a` contain *chapters* for each one of the original input files (each chapter just needs a number, not a name).

I have tried googling for this, but everything I have found seems to be about merging *video* files and MKVs, not m4a files.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this via the command line, as I have 60+ folders, and would like to be able to script this rather than loading it into an app of some sort.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I use [`mp4v2`](https://github.com/TechSmith/mp4v2) in my open-source app to [join together iTunes tracks](https://www.davidschlachter.com/misc/trackconcat). You can install `mp4v2` using Homebrew.

To add chapters, create a text file in the following format:

```
00:00:00.000 Name of first chapter
00:00:23.500 Name of second chapter
00:02:40.700 Third chapter, etc
```

You might be able to automate the creation of the chapter file by using `ffprobe` (see [example](https://github.com/davidschlachter/itunes-concatenator/blob/f00d21787dce3a096a0f54ef7d08d0d36b27f1e8/itunes-concatenator/itunes-concatenator/DASAppDelegate.applescript#L302-L339) written in AppleScript and shell script).

For an output file called "OUTPUT.m4a", save the chapters file as "OUTPUT.chapters.txt". Then run `mp4chaps -i OUTPUT.m4a` in the same directory as the output file to add the chapters to it.